# Why are my generator methods not inherited?

Tags: yeoman, lodash, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to make a generator that I can then extend to form similar sub-generators

Here's my base generator:

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

var VolumeAdderBase = module.exports = generators.Base.extend({

    initializing: function() {
        /* ... */
    },

    prompting: function () {
        /* ... */
    },

    writing: function () {
        /* ... */
    }

});
```

Here's an example sub-generator:

```
var VolumeAdderBase = require('../../utils/VolumeAdderBase.js');

// console.log(VolumeAdderBase);

module.exports = VolumeAdderBase.extend({

    fileType: "tomcat script",
    containerName: "tomcat",
    containerVolumeLocation: "/opt/tomcat/client-conf/"
});
```

When I try to run my sub-generator, it does nothing at all. No errors, no nothing.

When I dump the `VolumeAdderBase` object, there are plenty of methods on there, but they are all the `Base` ones. The ones defined in `VolumeAdderBase` are missing.

Am I missing something here? Or is there a better way to create similar sub-generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yeoman-generator` is only going to run [top level methods](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/base.js#L385) (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype)`). It doesn't go deeper in the prototype; that's by design. If Yeoman was to dig in the prototype, you couldn't use methods like `this.destinationPath()` or any other helpers as they'd all be schedule to be run - which would just break.

We have plans to [support mixin](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/733) in the future. But that's not currently the case.

As a fix, you can manually assign these methods:

```
VolumeAdderBase.prototype.prompting = VolumeAdderBase.prototype.prompting;
// etc...
```